# Multiple default IPv6 gateways

Tags: routing, ipv6

Why is not possible to have multiple default IPv6s gateways configured?

On Linux I'm not able to execute two "ip -6 route add default via [gw_ip]", while I'm able to do so with IPv4.

Comment: You might have done that with IPv4, but only one default gateway ever has effect, unless you have configured something additional such as those suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition there can only be one default gateway per routing table. Same is true for IPv4.

If you want to route traffic to several gateways this is how to do it:

1. Enable source based routing.
2. Create additional virtual routers (a.k.a. routing tables) and create default routes for each table.
3. Create rule defining which router to use with what source address.

Here is [an example](http://blog.altimos.de/2013/07/ipv6-source-address-routing-with-multiple-uplinks-sixxs/) to give you a better idea.